# Remove from string using JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with a list of filenames such as

var string = '1.jpg,2.jpg,3.png,4.jpg,5.webp'

Is there a way to remove everything that doesn't end in .jpg so the output would look like this:

var newstring = '1.jpg,2.jpg,4.jpg'

Comment: With regex: `var newstring = '1.jpg,2.jpg,3.png,4.jpg,5.webp,6.jpgg,7.jjpg,8.jpg'.replace(/,?[^,]+\.(?!jpg(,|$)).+?(?=,|$)/gmi, '');`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may write something like this

```
 string
        .split(",")
        .filter(value => value.endsWith(".jpg"))
        .join(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you experiment with possible regular expressions you could use? You might be able to find the answer yourself thanks to this page from the Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

If your string is always a comma separated list, then split the string on commas, which will give you an array of items. Then splice the array and remove items that contain the .jpg pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = '1.jpg,2.jpg,3.png,4.jpg,5.webp';
string.split(',').filter((name)=> name.includes('.jpg')).join(',');
//"1.jpg,2.jpg,4.jpg"
```

Comment: Note: includes and ends with is not the same.  This will fail on  (unlikely?) filenames such as 2.convertedfrom.jpg.to.png

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = '1.jpg,2.jpg,3.png,4.jpg,5.webp';

var stringArray=string.split(',');
newArray=[];

stringArray.forEach(element => {
  if(element.indexOf('.jpg')>-1){ newArray.push(element)}
});

console.log("jpg Array  :"+newArray)// output : jpg Array  :1.jpg,2.jpg,4.jpg
```